# First instance of X within a rolling 7 day window for a year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sliding-window

I'm trying to find the first instance of when a customer encounters a bug within rolling a 7 day window. I'm planning on using this to see how the customer behaves during the following days, e.g. do they place an order, or do they have a long period away before returning to site.

So what I'm looking to get is a table that contains:

```
Customer, Date, ReceiptID
Jack, 07/05/2018 , 223A
```

That's the firstinstance in 7 days window. He then encounters the bug again on 09/05/2018, which we don't count because it's within 7 days of the first one.

He then encounters a bug on the 18/08/2018 and I want to have this included in my results.

Considering a customer might theoretically have encountered over 30 bugs in a 7 day window, is there away to do this simply in SQL server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()` to get the reports that are 7+ days from the preceding report:

```
select b.*
from (select b.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by customer order by date) as prev_date
      from bugs b
     ) b
where prev_date is null or prev_date < dateadd(day, -7, date);
```

Note that if you have a sequence such as 1-6-12-18-24 then this will count as one "7-day" period because there is no larger gap for these reports.

Comment: Thanks for being so speedy. Didn't think about the scenario you've shown. Do you know if there is a way to get around this, as I would like to count the 12  as the second instance and the 24 as the third.

Comment: @Amar . . . It is possible but the query would be much more expensive.  I would suggest that you ask another question, and be very explicit about how you want to handle these cases (so it is not a duplicate of this question).